# filtering data in python from scraping bs4

Tags: python-3.x, filter, beautifulsoup

I'm a bit of confused on how to filter data I get from **scraping** data on ebay, here the code below :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url ='https://www.ebay.fr/sch/267/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=star+wars&_sop=10&_ipg=200'

def get_data(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    return soup

def parse(soup):
    results = soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 's-item__info clearfix'})
    for item in results:
        data = []
        try:
            Title = item.find('h3', {'class': 's-item__title'}).text.replace('Nouvelle annonce','')
            Price = item.find('span', {'class':'s-item__price'}).text
            Link = item.find('a', {'class' : 's-item__link'})['href']

            products = {'Title' : Title, 'Price' : Price, 'Link' : Link}
            data.append(products)
            print(data)

        except:
            continue
    return
soup = get_data(url)
parse(soup)
```

With that code I get all the books from ebay's page, but I only want a specific book from the list I get when I `print(data)` by using a keyword like :

```
[{'Title': 'Star Wars - Rebels T05', 'Price': '8,53 EUR', 'Link': 'https://www.ebay.fr/itm/265401372083?hash=item3dcb278db3:g:g00AAOSwTmBhjXjq'}]
[{'Title': 'Official Lego� Star Wars Annual 2016 (Lego Annuals), , Used; Good Book', 'Price': '8,42 EUR', 'Link': 'https://www.ebay.fr/itm/165178509530?hash=item26756808da:g:NU4AAOSwsldhjXi2'}]
[{'Title': 'Thrawn (Star Wars) de Zahn, Timothy | Livre | état très bon', 'Price': '10,95 EUR', 'Link': 'https://www.ebay.fr/itm/124998742900?hash=item1d1a817374:g:zBQAAOSwSGFhjXPt'}]
[{'Title': 'STARFIX 007 1983 STAR WARS La guerre des étoiles III Les PREDATEURS GWENDOLINE', 'Price': '12,90 EUR', 'Link': 'https://www.ebay.fr/itm/294540446774?hash=item4493fa8c36:g:EMUAAOSwWjxhjXNe'}]
[{'Title': 'Star Wars, Der Kristallstern de McIntyre, Vonda N.,... | Livre | état acceptable', 'Price': '3,53 EUR', 'Link': 'https://www.ebay.fr/itm/124998670341?hash=item1d1a805805:g:6xIAAOSwKmZhjWPn'}]
```

I would like to use the keyword : "Thrawn" so I get only the 3rd line :

```
[{'Title': 'Thrawn (Star Wars) de Zahn, Timothy | Livre | état très bon', 'Price': '10,95 EUR', 'Link': 'https://www.ebay.fr/itm/124998742900?hash=item1d1a817374:g:zBQAAOSwSGFhjXPt'}]
```

at this point I'm stuck, I tried many attempts with `if`, `string`, `attrs` but until now I get no result, so how can I implement "keyword" ? :)

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to find the book titles that contains the keyword 'Thrawn.'

First the individual data elements are dictionary, so a basic string has to be modified using str(dict).

```
book_titles = parse(soup)
book = [title for title in book_titles if 'Thrawn' in str(title)]
print(book)
# output 
[{'Title': 'Thrawn (Star Wars) de Zahn, Timothy | Livre | état très bon', 'Price': '10,95 EUR', 'Link': 'https://www.ebay.fr/itm/124998742900?hash=item1d1a817374:g:zBQAAOSwSGFhjXPt'}, {'Title': 'Star Wars™ Thrawn de Zahn, Timothy | Livre | état très bon', 'Price': '10,77 EUR', 'Link': 'https://www.ebay.fr/itm/124997651763?hash=item1d1a70cd33:g:FhoAAOSwPF9hjIs-'}]
```

book_titles = parse(soup)
Here is another way to do this with a regex.

```
book = [title for title in book_titles if regex.search('Thrawn',  str(title))]
print(book)
# output 
[{'Title': 'Thrawn (Star Wars) de Zahn, Timothy | Livre | état très bon', 'Price': '10,95 EUR', 'Link': 'https://www.ebay.fr/itm/124998742900?hash=item1d1a817374:g:zBQAAOSwSGFhjXPt'}, {'Title': 'Star Wars™ Thrawn de Zahn, Timothy | Livre | état très bon', 'Price': '10,77 EUR', 'Link': 'https://www.ebay.fr/itm/124997651763?hash=item1d1a70cd33:g:FhoAAOSwPF9hjIs-'}]
```

and here is another way:

```
book_titles = parse(soup)
for title in book_titles:
    for key, value in title.items():
        if key == 'Title':
            if 'Thrawn' in value:
                print(title)
                # output 

                {'Title': 'Thrawn (Star Wars) de Zahn, Timothy | Livre | état très bon', 'Price': '10,95 EUR',
                 'Link': 'https://www.ebay.fr/itm/124998742900?hash=item1d1a817374:g:zBQAAOSwSGFhjXPt'}

                {'Title': 'Star Wars™ Thrawn de Zahn, Timothy | Livre | état très bon', 'Price': '10,77 EUR',
                 'Link': 'https://www.ebay.fr/itm/124997651763?hash=item1d1a70cd33:g:FhoAAOSwPF9hjIs-'}
```

The function parse also need to return the data, so do this:

```
def parse(soup):
    data = []
    results = soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 's-item__info clearfix'})
    for item in results:
        try:
            Title = item.find('h3', {'class': 's-item__title'}).text.replace('Nouvelle annonce','')
            Price = item.find('span', {'class':'s-item__price'}).text
            Link = item.find('a', {'class': 's-item__link'})['href']

            products = {'Title': Title, 'Price': Price, 'Link': Link}
            data.append(products)
        except:
            continue
    return data
```

Here is one way to look for multiple books:

```
book_titles = parse(soup)
for title in book_titles:
    for key, value in title.items():
        if key == 'Title':
            for book in ['INTEGRALE', 'Thrawn']:
                if book in value:
                    print(title)
                    # output 

                    {'Title': 'Thrawn (Star Wars) de Zahn, Timothy | Livre | état très bon', 'Price': '10,95 EUR',
                     'Link': 'https://www.ebay.fr/itm/124998742900?hash=item1d1a817374:g:zBQAAOSwSGFhjXPt'}

                    {'Title': 'DARK MAUL INTEGRALE , STAR WARS LEGENDES, LIVRE NEUF (RARE) ', 'Price': '25,00 EUR',
                     'Link': 'https://www.ebay.fr/itm/175018282734?hash=item28bfe70eee:g:t1YAAOSwOsFhhW1Q'}

                    {'Title': 'LES OMBRES DE L EMPIRE INTEGRALE , STAR WARS LEGENDES, LIVRE NEUF ',
                     'Price': '20,00 EUR',
                     'Link': 'https://www.ebay.fr/itm/175018277970?hash=item28bfe6fc52:g:ASgAAOSwyFphhWsW'}

                    {'Title': 'Star Wars™ Thrawn de Zahn, Timothy | Livre | état très bon', 'Price': '10,77 EUR',
                     'Link': 'https://www.ebay.fr/itm/124997651763?hash=item1d1a70cd33:g:FhoAAOSwPF9hjIs-'}
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) I actually set the if condition inside the Try/except I guess that why it didn't work. I tried the 3rd way you wrote it works perfectly

Comment: and what if I want to search among multiple keyword ? I tried the following :
`keywords = {'INTEGRALE', 'Thrawn'}`
`for title in book_titles:
    for key, value in title.items():
        if key == 'Title':
            if keywords in value:
                print(title)`
so I get all the books containing the word : INTEGRALE, Thrawn, etc... but it's says :
`TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not set`

Comment: Look at the updated part of my answer.  Is this what you want to do?

Comment: Yes it's perfect :) thank you 
so, `for .... in ...` : allow you to convert/declare data you want in a certain way ?

Comment: for .... in ... is a for loop,  ref: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp